# Using SDL to write into a GTK2 window

Tags: c, gtk, sdl

I'm attempting to learn `SDL` and would like to use `GTK2` as the GUI framework under `Centos 5.8`. I've looked at some sample code, but so far I've not able to get any to compile.

For example, I tried this [sdl-gtk-demo](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/gtk-demo/) but it appears to require an older version of `GTK`?

What is required for an `SDL` application to draw onto a `GTK2` widget or window? My set up is the following:

1. Centos 5.8
2. GTK2
3. The standard GCC that comes with Centos 5.8

Because this is targeted for an embedded system, I don't have the liberty to use a newer `Centos` distribution. Similar questions exist, but I don't believe they talk about using such an old version of `Centos`.

EDIT: So perhaps a solution may be to write a standalone `SDL` application that uses OpenGL to do my image animation and write to the X11 window ID of a `GTK2` widget. Does this seem like a reasonable approach?

Comment: Typically, you program in *either* GTK+ (somewhat heavier-weight, largely for GUI interfaces) *or* SDL (for games, and simpler UIs).  Not both in the same program at the same time.  If you want two different programs to "communicate", then it's much better to send "messages" (with a pipe, a socket, a message queue, etc.) and have the application manage it's *own* drawing.  IMHO...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I would normally agree, but the requirement is to do some simple animation in a GTK2 application because we can't use Cairo. So unfortunately I'm stuck needing to integrate `SDL` and `GTK`.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579967/sdl-surface-into-gtk-window/48862807#48862807