# SDL_Surface into GTK Window

Tags: c, image-processing, gtk, sdl

I'm currently making a project in my IT School and I work with SDL (The project is image processing and stuff like that), and currently I just display the image with SDL without interface (buttons etc...). I know a little bit about GTK so I want to know if I can display an image (here a SDL_Surface) into a GTK window 
I made some research but nothing was very clear...
Thank you !

Comment: GTK is tipically used with [cairo](http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/cairobackends/), not with SDL, but it is trivial to make your own buttons using the mouse-motion events of SDL.

Comment: Yeah but the window wouldn't be as good as a GTK window :/

Comment: @Zenor27 probably the most stable way is using offscreen rendering surface and copying pixels to GTK canvas. Not very fast though. Other ways are platform specific, e.g. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284284/how-to-render-sdl2-texture-into-gtk3-window

Answer (score 1):

**Drawing widgets using SDL**

Drawing widgets(menu, buttons etc) using SDL drawing functions and handling actions by tracking the cursor position during the occurrence of event(on which item the cursor was while the event was performed).
This becomes very complicated and would be better to use an existing GUI library with some simple hacks. You can find code example for drawing a button [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/175010-creating-buttonsmenus-in-sdl/).

**Copying SDL surface into target GUI widget**

This involves copying pixel by pixel(predefined functions might be available to do the same, *gdk_draw_rgb_image* in case of gtk) of the sdl surface into target gui widget(can be a drawingArea in case of GTK).

**Merging SDL window into a GUI widget**

In X11 and win32 systems each windows are given with a window id and by default sdl and gtk would have separate window id resulting two different windows, we can exploit *SDL_CreateWindowFrom* function to use single window for sdl and gtk in which we will force both the libraries to use a single window id.
You can find similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284284/how-to-render-sdl2-texture-into-gtk3-window).

**GTK Plug and Socket**

Plug and Socket enables embeeding widget from one process to another. GTK will create a socket and pass the socket id to SDL and SDL would create window from that socket ID.

**Event loop handling:**
After merging SDL with GTK you might find gtk and sdl have their own event loops hence handling events might not be as expected. To solve that issue you can handle
events in GTK and propagate the event to SDL using *SDL_PushEvent* function and vice versa in case you are using user defined events.

```
.
.
static SDL_Event SDLevent;
switch(event->keyval)
{
    case GDK_KEY_m:
       SDLevent.type = SDL_KEYUP;
       SDLevent.key.keysym.sym = SDLK_m;
       SDL_PushEvent(&SDLevent);
       break;
       .
       .
       .
```

This [link](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/FAQ_GUI) has a nice explanation for above methods.